# Is it possible to change the order of rendering directives in AngularJS 1

Tags: angularjs

I have a route with a controller, a resolve for the initial request and a view. The view has a few directives. I have noticed that the view is rendered first then the directives. There is small movement on the page because of directives. Is it possible to change the order of rendering or fix it in some other way?

Comment: What is the order you desire?

Comment: the directives to come prerendered with the view somehow and not after the view is shown

Answer (score 1):

I think something like that can work

in the view

```
<your-directive></your-directive>

<div ng-show="showAfterDirective" ng-include="path_to_view">
  <p>or just insert it here without ng-include</p>
</div>
```

in your controller

```
    angular.module("YourModule).controller("yourCtrl", function($scope){
     var init = function(){
       $scope.showAfterDirective = true // you can use timeout here, or two way data binding with the directive if it's a custom one
     }

init();

});
```